# There is a code drawing a heart. How to insert a photo inside this figure so that the remaining background does not change?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

There is a code drawing a heart. How to insert a photo inside this figure so that the remaining background does not change?

```
import time
import math
import turtle
def xt(t):
    return 16 * math.sin(t) ** 3
def yt(t):
    return 13 * math.cos(t) - 5 * \
        math.cos(2 * t) - 2 * \
        math.cos(3 * t) - \
        math.cos(4 * t)
t = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.Screen().screensize(1040, 1080)
t.speed(1500)
turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.Screen().bgcolor(0, 0, 0)
time.sleep(2)
for i in range(300):
    t.goto((xt(i) * 20, yt(i) * 20))
    t.pencolor((255 - i) % 255, i % 255, (255 + i) // 2 % 255)
    t.goto(0, 0)
t.hideturtle()
turtle.update()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the combination of `register_shape()` and `stamp()` to place an image atop the drawing.  Below is an example of doing this as well as some tweaks of your original code:

```
from math import sin, cos
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def xt(t):
    return 16 * sin(t) ** 3

def yt(t):
    return 13 * \
        cos(1 * t) - 5 * \
        cos(2 * t) - 2 * \
        cos(3 * t) - \
        cos(4 * t)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1040, 1080)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.colormode(255)
screen.register_shape("picture.gif")

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

for i in range(300):
    turtle.goto((xt(i) * 20, yt(i) * 20))
    turtle.pencolor((255 - i) % 255, i % 255, (255 + i) // 2 % 255)
    turtle.home()

turtle.shape("picture.gif")
turtle.stamp()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
import math
from turtle import *
speed(0)
bgcolor("black")
def hearta(k):
 return 15 * math.sin(k) ** 3
def heartb(k):
 return 12 * math.cos(k) - 5 * math.cos(2 * k) - 2 * math.cos(3 * k) - math.cos(4 * k)
for i in range(6000):
 goto(hearta(i) * 20, heartb(i) * 20)
 color("pink")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35727589)